# localStorage not working in IE9 and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-9, local-storage

I am working with localStorage. My code is perfectly working in Chrome, but not in IE9 and Firefox.

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restoreContents, false);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick=function(){saveContents('myList','contentMain', event, this);};

function amIclicked(e, eleObject)
{
    alert("amIClicked");
    e = e || event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert("target = " + target.id);
    if(target.id=='pageBody' || target.id=='Save')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function saveContents(e, d, eveObj, eleObject) {
    //alert("saveContents");
    if (amIclicked(eveObj, eleObject)) {
        var cacheValue = document.getElementById(e).innerHTML;
        var cacheKey = "key_" + selectedKey;
        var storage = window.localStorage;
        //alert ("cacheKey = " + cacheKey + " ,cacheValue = " + cacheValue); 
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undifined"){
        localStorage.setItem("cacheKey","cacheValue");
        }
        //alert ("Saved!!"); 
        var dd = document.getElementById(d);
        //document.getElementById("contentMain").style.display == "none";       
        dd.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function restoreContents(e,k) {
    //alert("test");
    if(k.length < 1) { return; }
    var mySavedList = localStorage["key_" + k];

    if (mySavedList != undefined) {
        document.getElementById(e).innerHTML = mySavedList;
    }
}


    <a onclick="ShowContent('contentMain','myList','Sample_1'); return true;" href="#" >Sample 1</a><br/><br/>
    <a onclick="ShowContent('contentMain','myList','Sample_2'); return true;" href="#" >Sample 2</a><br/><br/>

    <div style="display:none;display:none;position:absolute;border-style: solid;background-color: white;padding: 5px;"id="contentMain">
    <ol id="myList" contenteditable="true">
        <li>Enter Content here</li>
    </ol>
<!--<input id="editToggleButton" type="button" value="Edit"/>-->
</div>
```

when I tried to debug the code in Firefox with Firebug, I am getting the error in different line. I am totally confused here :)

Here is the code where I am getting the error:

```
function amIclicked(e, eleObject)
{
    alert("amIClicked");
    e = e || event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert("target = " + target.id);
    if(target.id == 'pageBody' || target.id == 'Save'){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the error I am getting in Mozilla Firefox is:

```
 target is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

alert("target = " + target.id);
```

I have declared the target in

```
<body id="pageBody">
```

too much confused

Comment: Could the typo perhaps be causing your issue?  `if(typeof(Storage)!=="undifined"){` Undefined is spelled wrong. Not sure how that's working in Chrome. Is this your actual, real code?

Comment: Are you working on localhost? localstorage is only available on HTTP websites.

Comment: @eric.itzhak localhost is through http(I've used localStorage on localhost), you probably mean filesystem

Comment: @eric.itzhak - `file://` != `http://localhost`. Where it doesn't work is when there is no webserver at all, and you're using the file protocol. Localhost still uses http and should work.

Comment: @eric.itzhad Local storage works for me on localhost. Perhaps you meant to say that since local host doesn't automatically include a server, you have to install Apache or some such.

Comment: i meant filestystem, my bad :)

Comment: maha, can you please tell us if you see any error messages in your debugger? Just simply telling us "it doesn't work" really doesn't help solve the problem. In IE9, go in the tools menu and click "F12 Developer Tools", then look for errors in the console.

Comment: hi all 

I have spelled wrongly here undefined but in my code it was been given undefined only it was working fine in google chrome

Comment: i have full code withe me 

is that possible to attach here in stack overflow

Comment: No maha, that won't help. You need to do some of this research on your own to help us help you ;)  For instance, what you can do for us is to try and narrow down the problem for us. Where exactly does it fail? Does it fail when you set the value or when you get the value? Where is the discrepancy? Your debugger can show you if something you're doing in your code is creating errors.

Comment: If it helps, your code -- oddly -- works for me in IE9. Are you *sure* you're in IE9 and not IE8/7? Also, can you add what version of Firefox you're using?

Comment: hi jmort i am using ie9, firefox and google chrome

Comment: What is the url you're using to access the page?  `http://localhost`? or something else? Are those alerts you have in your code firing when you perform the operation that should store the data? Basically, to answer this question, we need more details such as this. Tell us what you've tried. Tell us what you see when you run the code, tell us what you're expecting to see. These things will be very helpful. Please make an [edit] to your question, using that link, to add all these extra details. (This also pushes your question back to the top so everyone sees.) Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're checking to see if localstorage exists is a bit unorthodox and may actually fail to detect that a legacy browser doesn't have localstorage. Below, you have typos in this code, such as "undifined":

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
//alert ("cacheKey = " + cacheKey + " ,cacheValue = " + cacheValue); 
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undifined"){
    localStorage.setItem("cacheKey","cacheValue");
}
```

Instead, here is the correct way to check if localStorage is available:

```
if(window.localStorage) { 
    localStorage.setItem("cacheKey","cacheValue"); 
}
```

With that said, that's not actually causing your problem in this case. Instead, you pointed out that the debugger found an error on this line:

```
if(k.length < 1) { return; }
```

You also see the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined sample_1.html, line 157 character 3
```

The key piece of information in that error message is that the **object is null**. In other words, you're passing in a null value as an argument for the parameter k!

The DOMContentLoaded event doesn't pass in this parameter; thus, it may be easiest for you to just simply use a global variable for now, something that you can access from within the `restoreContents` function.

Also, as @omri pointed out in his answer, +1 BTW, you're passing cacheKey into localStorage as a string and not as the actual variable that represents your key. This is the correct usage:

```
localStorage.setItem(cacheKey, cacheValue);
```

This may not be all of the problems in your code, but this should get you started. The best, most useful tip I can suggest for you, since I can tell you're new to this, is to *learn how to use those browser debuggers* and learn to recognize what error messages mean. Google the error messages if you have to. If you can learn to use these tools, you'll find it becomes much easier to recognize certain problems and then come up with a plan to resolve them. Good luck! :)

Comment: and omri both of thank you very much for your suggestions I will try my level best to solve this issue if it is not solved again i will post where the issue is coming from  thank you very much for all give me the support

Comment: maha, you're welcome. If you get stuck on a problem in the future, remember to take your time in writing your question and be sure to include what you tried, what you expect to see, and what error messages you're getting. Again, read up on those debuggers ;) As you master them, you'll find that they help you narrow down the problem into smaller chunks, which will seem less overwhelming to you (and to those who help you). Good luck, and we're happy to help! :)

Comment: Hi @jmort just now i checked the above code is not working for the first time in google chrome itself  :(

Comment: Maha, as I mentioned to you earlier, "Not working" doesn't tell us anything. You have to be specific. Also, the above code is "working code" (verified in IE9) that solves the localStorage question, you likely have other problems in code that you didn't show, and you'll need to work through each problem individually. If you're stuck on something specific, please feel free to ask a question that targets *that* specific issue. However, know that if you provide no details, there is little anyone can do to help. Good luck :)

Comment: This also works in Chrome. (Just verified, again). Again, the problem is likely elsewhere in the code, and you'll need to *use your debugger* to determine what you're doing wrong or at least get error messages that can be used to help you. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi all 

now I am not getting any error in the chrome and firefox but the current code is working for the second time of the page reloads i don't no why it is rendering like that please help me out

Answer (score 2):

Does this work in any browser?!
you've got "cacheValue" as a string,
typeof Storage will never equal to "undifined" (undefined maybe),
and the variable selectedKey was never defined.

Comment: hi jmort


when I tried debugging in iexplore 

function restoreContents(e,k) {
  //alert("test");
  if(k.length < 1) { return; }
     var mySavedList = localStorage["key_" + k];
      
     if (mySavedList != undefined) {
         document.getElementById(e).innerHTML = mySavedList;
     }
 }

when i debugging in ie9 i am getting error this particular line

if(k.length < 1) { return; }

Comment: @maha - You should follow my advice in the comment on your question and add this detail to your question using the edit feature. This is very helpful! ;)

Comment: @maha - Also, please add what the error says. Errors actually do mean something and are important to understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several Steps :) for localstorage we need http then only it will work in IE9

But finally with the help of Tomcat i have created http: from there i have run the localstorage html file it was working fine .

Thanks for the people who supported me here

Thank you 
m